# Feeding stateful and stateful-effectful computations into each other

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing code that runs a simulation in an interactive way. The building blocks are:

```
runStep :: I -> State S O
runWorld :: World m -> O -> StateT W m I
```

Note that the world has some state `W` but is also allowed to have effects of type `m`. My question is about the function that feeds `runStep` and `runWorld` into each other. My current implementation is quite heavy on the `Control.Lens` noise:

```
sim :: (Monad m) => World m -> StateT (I, S, O) m Result
sim w = do
  inp <- use _1
  out <- zoom _2 $ state . runState $ runStep inp
  inp' <- zoom _3 $ runWorld w out
  _1 .= inp'
  return $ resultComputedPurelyFrom out
```

What I'd like to improve on this code is two things:

- Reduce the lens piping. I could, of course, get rid of `_1`, `_2` and `_3` by using a bespoke record type, but then that introduces its own noise -- `sim` is the only function that uses this particular combination of `I`, `S` and `O`.
- The write-back to `inp'` could easily be accidentally omitted, resulting in not-obviously-wrong-looking, well-typed code that wouldn't work correctly.

**ETA**: An alternative formulation is to forego the lens stuff completely,  at the cost of making even the updating of the `S` component something that can be accidentally omitted:

```
sim :: (Monad m) => World m -> StateT (I, S) (StateT O m) Result
sim w = do
  (inp, s) <- get 
  let (out, s') = runState (runStep inp) s
  inp' <- lift $ runWorld w out
  put (inp', s')
  return $ resultComputedPurelyFrom out
```

Answer (score 3):

> What I'd like to improve on this code is two things:
>
> - Reduce the lens piping. I could, of course, get rid of `_1`, `_2` and `_3` by using a bespoke record type, but then that introduces its own noise -- `sim` is the only function that uses this particular combination of `I`, `S` and `O`.

Is this really a problem? I don't understand what could be improved about that part.

> - The write-back to `inp'` could easily be accidentally omitted, resulting in not-obviously-wrong-looking, well-typed code that
>   wouldn't work correctly.

You can move the state-passing of `I` into a separate function for which that's the only job:

```
withInput :: ALens' s i -> (i -> StateT s i) -> StateT s ()
withInput l go = do
  i <- use (cloneLens l)
  i' <- go i
  cloneLens l := i'

...
sim = do
  withInput _1 $ \inp ->
    inp' <- ...
    pure inp'
  ...
```

The result type `()` of `withInput` makes it difficult to forget to update the state: the function would fail to typecheck if you forget the last clause.

Comment: The lens noise is a problem for my use case because this is for a book I'm writing, and the less lens experience required, the easier it will be for some of my readers.